# Convert $-2xy+2zx-x^2$ into a sum of three squares of expressions of $x,y$ and $z$

Tags: linear-algebra

Convert $-2xy+2zx-x^2$ into a sum of three non-zero squares of linearly independent expressions of $x,y$ and $z$

I can do 2: $-(x+y-z)^2+(y-x)^2$ , but I  need exactly 3 squares.

Got stuck on a little riddle here. Is there any general theory for it?

Comment: $(x-x)^2-(x+y-z)^2+(y-x)^2$

Comment: @ShreyasPimpalgaonkar i need exactly 3 non-zero squares. Sorry, should have mentioned that

Comment: @user376343 no but i have this exact same thing in the question body already, the left square should be zero if the other two are like mine :)

Comment: $\frac{(y-x)^2}{2}-(x+y-z)^2+ \frac{(y-x)^2}{2}$

Comment: @ShreyasPimpalgaonkar I should add linear independability too

Comment: @NickTheDick expand your squares, you will not obtain $-2xy+2zx-x^2$ (??)

Comment: The second term should be be y-z squared

Comment: @user376343 yes but those are not squares

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you’re asking for is impossible.

Let $$Q=\begin{bmatrix}-1&-1&1\\-1&0&0\\1&0&0\end{bmatrix}$$ so that your quadratic form can be written as $(x,y,z)Q(x,y,z)^T$. Your problem is then equivalent to finding some invertible $3\times3$ matrix $P$ such that $D=P^TQP$ is diagonal and has no zeros along the main diagonal.

Observe that $\det(Q)=0$, so $\det(D)=\det(P^TQP)=\det(Q)\det(P)^2=0$, but this means that at least one of those main-diagonal elements must be zero. In other words, no matter how you rewrite this quadratic form as a linear combination of independent perfect squares, you will have at most two terms.